# Difficulty in changing the background color of a particular row in an Android Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, colors, background

I am confused in changing the background colour of a particular row in an list view, below is the code I tried. Different rows gets highlighted as i scroll the list, I could like to understand the reason behind this. The logic seems to quite simple, but the results are unpredictable. How am I supposed to achieve this.

```
 @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ViewHolder holder;
      if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rows_for_layout, null);
             holder = new ViewHolder(); 
             holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
             holder.rated=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rated);
              convertView.setTag(holder);   
            }else {
              holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            } 

          //selected_position is the position where the list has to be highlighted  
            if(position==selected_position){
              holder.name.setText(elements.get(position).get("name"));
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlight_this);
            holder.rated.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star_image);
             }else{
               holder.name.setText(elements.get(position).get("name"));

             }


      return convertView;
     }//getView ![alt text][1]
```

Comment: don't see any problem with the code, when are you changing/updating 'selected_position' variable ?

Comment: I am setting the values for the variable 'selected_position' in onCreate() method ,for reference please check this url for full code http://pastebin.com/ki7q6Wy0

Comment: you can check the image at http://i56.tinypic.com/10x7rsw.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your else statement does not reset the background color to its original. The getView method can recycle a view that was previously in your list but is not visible anymore. If the background was changed, then it will still be that background color from when it was originally created, which can depend on your state.

So, to "reset" that, add the following in your else:

```
if(position==selected_position){
          holder.name.setText(elements.get(position).get("name"));
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlight_this);
        holder.rated.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star_image);
         }else{
           holder.name.setText(elements.get(position).get("name"));
           //Add this
           convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.not_highlighted);
         }
```

Comment: But still, why would you work that way? I instead would use a selector as background, with a selected/unselected/... state? It is much cleaner than the current approach.

Comment: thanks eMich for your response ,but i have a list view selector already and its done as you said,this one is apart from that ,I just need to highlight only one particular row in a list to show that this one is special.I have restored to use "R.drawable.highlight_this" for the special row and a transparent drawable for the rest.